# Is it bad to work with pixels in CSS?

Tags: css, pixel, screen-resolution, resolution-independence

Is it bad in terms of compatibility to use pixel numbers in CSS instead of percentages? How about lower resolutions? Is it okay to work with them in ranges of 1-100?

Answer (score 47):

All of the measurements have their own purposes:

- **Use pixels for pixel-based things**, like borders. You probably don't want a border that ends up being 1.3422 pixels wide.
- **Use text-centric measures (em, ex) for text-based things**, like content areas, labels, and input boxes. It's an easy way to make sure you have room for text of a certain length and width.
- **Use percents for window-based things**, like columns.

There are exceptions, of course. For example, you might want to specify a minimum column width in pixels. But follow the above and your pages will scale well. ALWAYS zoom in and out on your pages to see how they work with different font sizes and browser shapes -- don't get surprised later.

Comment: This is the right answer. If you design with scalability in mind from the beginning, your life will be easier in the future. Liquid widths should certainly not be considered advanced functionality or time consuming as suggested by Venemo. Not to mention sizing fonts in px (never do this - ever).

Comment: @Bryan - some designs are not designed with scalability in mind by the designers. Eg. if you receive a psd file from a designer that is absolutely not intended to scale, why would you make it scalable?

Comment: @Venemo, that's a challenge. If you are getting designs 'tossed over the fence' from a graphic artist, perhaps you should re-examine your workflow so that you can collaborate better on the look of the site. You may also be able to pad the design creatively. Image borders in HTML5 look to make up for a lot of problems like this too, by allowing variable-width graphical borders to connect fixed-sized graphical elements.

Comment: @Alex, +1, I agree. Still, some clients don't require it or do not even care about it. In such cases, it is a waste of time and money. Agreed on HTML5, too. Unfortunately, I don't recommend to use it too much if you are concerned about legacy browsers or IE.

Comment: @Venemo - Fair point. I just watched [this DVD](http://forabeautifulweb.com/buy/designing_web_accessibility) which had many good points about designing accessible scalable layouts (and how to convince clients that they should use them).

Answer (score 41):

This is a difficult question, because the answer mostly depends on your situation.

Pixels are not that bad, I mostly use them too. (Sometimes even for font sizes.)
I usually fix the outer block element of the layout by a given size (pixels with fixed-width layouts, and percentages with fluid layouts), and on the inside elements I usually set percentages whenever possible.

There are some elements which simply can't be styled with percentages or `em`s, especially the more fancy stuff coming from graphical designers who don't understand such principles.

*For example:* if you have a column on your site with a simple style, you can set its width to a percentage easily, but if it has a background image with a specific width that is not designed with scaling in mind, it only looks good with a fixed-width. In such cases, you'll have to ensure that the rest of the page occupies the remaining width correctly.

Note that you can use pixels with percentages together.
For example, this is a snippet from one of my latest web apps:

```
min-width: 800px;
width: 80%;
max-width: 1500px;
```

The choice also depends on what design or layout you would like to achieve.

For a **fixed-width** layout, pixel values are fine. If a designer gives you a Photoshop image that contains really fancy stuff which would be extremely complicated to even think about how it would resize, you should definitely go for this.

If your layout needs to be **dynamic**, you should use percentages to make sure that it expands as the resolution changes, and you can use the above code snippet to make it look better in scenarios where it would otherwise look insane.

Some layouts (eg. imagine if StackOverflow would take up all the space) would look pretty ugly on a width of eg. 1920 pixels - the line widths would be so insanely high that it would be extremely unconvenient to read.
This is what `max-width` is for. Even in some dynamic layouts, you'll have to limit the maximal width of your site to maximize usability and readability.

And also take into consideration the smaller screens.
It is true that noone uses a 800×600 desktop anymore, but many people browse the web with mobile devices which have even smaller resolution.
This is what `min-width` is for: to make your dynamically expanded layout look less crowded on smaller resoultions.

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

The [Smashing Book](http://smashingbook.com) has some very nice thoughts about the subject.

**EDIT 2:**

I don't want my post to sound like I want you to force pixel-based sizing on your visitors.
(Apparently, some people in the comments misunderstood me in such a way.)

To clear it up:

I believe that the ideal layout is one that adjusts well to any possible resolution or setting.
However, we can't always do everything perfectly. Time/resources and the target audience are the key to determine if your site requires that advanced functionality or not.

*I'm suggesting that you use the right thing for the given job.*

If you are developing a site which will have a significant percentage of visitors who require more advanced adjustments to the site, it may be well worth it.
(Of course, sometimes we just do it for ourselves to have the feeling of doing things the right way, but is is not always a financially sound decision.)

Still, you should do the proper research about what sort of site will be it, who will be the visitors, and such stuff, before deciding about layouts, and whether it is worth the time to make them fluid or more dynamic.

Comment: Sizing things by pixel hoses over a lot of users. Most people have screenwidths of 1024 or more--but how wide is their browser window? What if it's open alongside four other windows, and they only want it to be 400px wide? Alternately -- what if their vision isn't that great, and they use 24 or 32pt fonts on a 30" monitor? Then your max width overconstrains them.

Comment: "the line widths would be so insanely high that it would be extremely unconvenient to read" -- this can be fixed by using a relative size, such as ems, which is a much better solution than forcing a pixel size on the user.

Comment: @Alex, @rmeador - It is all about what the target audience of the site is, and how much time do you want to spend on it. Of course, an ideal layout is one that adjusts correctly to every possible setting and resolution, but if 99% of your users  don't require it, then it is a waste of effort and money. **I'm not suggesting that what your saying is wrong, but it isn't always worth the effort.**

Comment: I see font sizes by ems are out now and px's are in. Hooray.

Comment: @Alex Feinman - People with 400px width of browser window can just expand it to the full screen. And almost everyone _will_ do this, if they see horizontal scrolling. 

btw - stackoverflow has fixed width 960px. 
Many google pages has fixed width too.

Comment: @Davinel - Exactly. Nothing is wrong with fixed width, if it is done right.

Answer (score 12):

### Font sizes

I think you must first **understand the issues** that exist with working with pixels in CSS:

- **Zoom in older browsers is broken.** For example, [IE6 and IE7 do not resize text when zooming](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss/). Line-height can be quirky too. These problems do not exist in modern browsers, but they are a reason why many shy away from using pixels for font sizes.
- Everybody will see **text the same size** if you specify the font size in pixels. Browsers have a default size of 16px for paragraphs, so if you only use `em` and other relative sizes, you will **respect the decision** of users who change this. This is especially important on text heavy sites, especially if there are more older users. On the other hand, if the design of a site is important I think it is possible and justifiable to use `px` to specify font sizes without breaking usability.

In the end, you need to make the decision yourself, and it does depend on the exact circumstances, but I think that **specifying font sizes in pixels is okay**.

By the way, when working with `em` to specify font size it is a **good idea** to set the `body` to `font-size: 62.5%`. This means the base font size is 10px, so 1em is 10px, 1.6em is 16px and so on, making it easier to **think in pixels while designing using ems**. I still find it frustrating to work like this, especially when the values of ems cascade. There are some very handy sites like [PXtoEM.com](http://pxtoem.com/) that help with this.

### Layout issues

The screen is a **pixel based layout**, so pixels are an intuitive choice for many things. The main issue here is that different users have **different screen sizes**. As others have pointed out, using `min-width` and `max-width` in pixels along with `width` in percent is a helpful way to respect the size of the screen, while preventing your site to be unreasonably squished or stretched on very small and very large windows.

However, I would generally avoid this approach in favour of [**CSS media queries**](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/). You can then use fixed width chunks and make the layout wider (amongst other things) as the screen size increases. However, CSS media queries, like all cool web technologies, suffers from lack of browser support. Most notably, IE8 and earlier do not support them, although there are JavaScript fixes. On the other hand, the iPhone and other handheld devices do support them, and I would strongly recommend them if you want your site to look nice on these devices.

I think **fixed width grids are fine**. Fixed width grid systems like [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/)
are popular enough in their own right, and there are so many other sites that have a fixed width, that I doubt you would hear many complaints if you did this. Handheld devices that do not have large screens are an issue, but this is where CSS media queries should be used, so it is **possible to specify everything in pixels** and have your site looking beautiful on the desktop and on the iPhone.

### Conclusion

Ultimately, everything depends on who your users are, what you need to support, and what you want your site to look like, but there is **nothing inherently wrong with using pixels in CSS**.

Comment: Just to point it out css 'pixels' are NOT display pixels

Answer (score 4):

That depends on what you are styling. For columns for example, the width should probably depend on the text size to ensure that it will look optimal on multiple resolutions/screens. If you want to divide your page in two parts, you should use percentages. But if you want a 1px border between these two parts, independent of the resolution, use pixels.

Answer (score 4):

Basically it depends on who's hiring you and consequently the audience of your work.
For institutional purposes (where content should prevail over the shape, like a goverment project), you better work with .em or %, they are harder to control, but they will be really user friendly in terms of accessibility.

If we talk about corporative Websites (Where shape is the deal) pixel will be a more accurate tool to fulfill your customer expectation regarding his brand.
A liquid interface (%, .em) is always a good stuff when it is smartly done, but don't forget to check your design under extreme conditions and be sure that it will be stable.

If you work with pixels, you will have absolute control over the final look of your site, but you will have to assume the impossibility for some user's to operate with it efficiently.

Best option: rather than designing a Website compatible for all platforms (what will result in a multi-deficiency design) suggest your customers special versions of the site adapted for every demand, what is a better practice and a better business for a designer too...

Comment: +1 for mentioning that it depends on your client and the target audience of the site.

Answer (score 2):

I would say avoid it if possible except for in certain cases.

For instance for a thin border it's ok to just specify 1px.

Also for `max-` and `min-` style attributes it is ok. But then make the non-max/min attribute be a percentage if possible.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `max-` and `min-` properties.

Answer (score 2):

This really is a good question which I have asked many times before. Not being a hardcore web designer (I'm more on the development side) I've usually asked the designers I work with about their opinions, and here is what I have distilled:

Using percentages vs pixels for sizing elements and so on is really a matter of personal taste or the requirements in each specific case. If you need it to scale, or it will scale well, use percentages. If not, use pixels. People here have used the examples of major columns in a page maybe needing to be fluid but borders may well need the precision of a pixel measurement.

Obviously sizing images is pretty much tied to their resolution and pixel units, so I always use them in this case.

However, using em sizing versus pixel or even point sizing for text is a whole different kettle of fish. Most of the guys I work with have a base reset style for font sizes which brings the size of 1em down to about 12px. They then use ems everywhere else (or as near to everywhere else as is possible) to size text elements, form controls and the like. This is how I operate now too as it seems to work well across a variety of browsers, OSes and DPIs on desktops and laptops. I can't vouch for mobile devices though.

Accessibility is the key though - if you need to make something usable for people with disabilities or work on a variety of devices out the box, even things you may consider old, then scaling will be a requirement. Build it into your model for designing the site from the get-go and you may realise that absolute pixel sizing is not even needed in that case.

For example, an art-heavy design is probably going to be designed at a single scale, but the new educational website for disabled users is going to have to work in a variety of situations.

Just remember, the W3C put a variety of methods for sizing and scaling into their specifications for a reason - flexibility. Do whatever fits best and works well for your audience (as Moustard said earlier).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a css/html expert but convention I use is to use pixels for the outer containers and percentages for the inner objects.

Another rule of thumb I have with anyone reviewing my layout is a *Three Pixel Rule*. It is rare that everything will line up exactly within every browser out there. We've agreed the effort outweighs the benefits to move anything three pixels or less.

Comment: +1 for "pixels for the outer containers and percentages for the inner objects". Still, this applies only to fixed-width layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Do the right thing by default.  If a user visits your site with javascript disabled and no preference cookies, you should serve them a web page that is as functional and accessible as possible.

Your *default* stylesheet should assume nothing about the browser window, and still render a functional page, however hideous, down to 320x320 resolution, and up to unbounded sizes.  If photographic fidelity is so important that you can't trust browser scaling, and sometimes it is, then you should use pixel measurements (at least minimums) for elements encapsulating images of fixed size, to make sure that you don't end up with important things being covered up.  Specifying minimum widths along with percentages should give you the control you need while giving your users the accessibility they need.  Even if accessibility isn't an issue now, it will be later if the site is successful.

When you *do* know more about the browser window, then it's okay to use fixed widths in alternate stylesheets, if the importance of preserving the design justifies the added work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting a fixed size then pixels are fine.  But if you want your layout to look good on various resolutions/screen sizes, then you should stick to more relative measures like percentages.  Most folks are targeting the latter.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok if that is what it takes to please your client. Most of the time, you can't balance the amount of space in diverse screen sizes with only percentages. CSS3 media queries helps here but adoption is still problematic.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer pixel in most cases.
For example - default width of content ares: 960px. 
In "1024" it will be ok, with small free spaces on the both side of the screen. Put some gradient or background there. In "1280" or "1440" or "1680", or whatever - there will be bigger and bigger gap, but it will look nice. 
Yep, for 800 - this site will be ugly. But who cares? Every major players dropped support for 800. There are too few people with this resolution..

There are many various sites, where %% will be much better solution, though.

Comment: In my opinion, support for 800px and lower widths should come back because of the emergence of mobile devices. Not everyone would want to take the effort to make their sites look good with mobiles, though.

Comment: @Venemo - I think making a mobile version of the site will be better solution.

Comment: I have a 1680px wide screen, yet often have multiple windows side by side, giving about 800px widths.  I wouldn't be surprised if multiple open windows is more common than not for technically savvy users.  Is this annoying for some sites?  Yes, but it's also still more useful than alternatives I've tried.  Vertical space seems much more essential for just about everything.

Answer (score -1):

The building blocks of a screen are pixels. You can't go wrong with fixed pixel sizes. As other posters have mentioned, you can also use percentages or "em"s for a scalable substitute.

Comment: -1. The building blocks of a web page are text, and graphics. Yes, they get translated into pixels eventually, but it's somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: @Alex - he didn't speak about building blocks of a web page, but building blocks of a screen.

Comment: @Alex is it irrelevant? Read the question again. "Is it bad in terms of compatibility to use pixel numbers in CSS instead of percentages? How about lower resolutions? Is it okay to work with them in ranges of 1-100?"