# Shouldn't we only use relative CSS units on typography?

Tags: css, font-size, typography, measurement

When I started finding my way in webdesign I always used 'px' units to define everything from marges, paddings, font-sizes etc. Then I switched over to relative units. Using EM and REM.

I understand the concept of using EM's or REM's for typography. Especially for responsive websites it comes in handy. But I don't get why I should use them for other elements than typography (for instance margins and paddings). Because when we set the font-size larger for small screens the margins and paddings will also increase, which is impractical for mobile devices and I don't want that.

So should we only use relative CSS units for typography? Or am I misunderstanding the dynamics of these relative units and using them wrong?

Comment: I agree; see more detail here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915508/is-it-bad-to-work-with-pixels-in-css/2916269#2916269

Answer (score 1):

I would use relative measurements for vertical paddings and margins but fixed for horizontal. That way vertical rhythm is kept when font-sizes are changes by the users' device, but doesn't squash everything up horizontally.